# Query a mongo object - aggregation

Tags: mongodb, nested, aggregation

I have a json like this :

```
[
  {
    "Customer_ID": 1,
    "Order": [
      {
        "Item": "A",
        "Price": 2,
        "Quantity": 6
      },
      {
        "Item": "B",
        "Price": 3,
        "Quantity": 6
      },
      {
        "Item": "C",
        "Price": 2,
        "Quantity": 8
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want a result something like this :

Total price is multiplication of Price and Quantity

customer,total_price

```
1,46

2,..

3,..
```

can someone please help me with the mongo query for it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help you,

```
[{
    $project: {
        customer: '$Customer_ID',
        values: {
            $map: {
               input: '$Order',
               as: 'item',
               'in': { $multiply: [ '$$item.Price', '$$item.Quantity' ]}
            }
        }
    }
 }, 
 {
     $project: {
         customer:'$customer',
         totalValue: {
             $sum: '$values'
         }
     }
 }]
```

Let me explain what is happening here, at the first **$project** block we are projecting **Customer_ID** as **customer** and multiplication of each **Order**'s **Price** and **Quantity**  as **values**. Then in the next **$project** block we are adding all the items in **values** array and projecting as **totalValue**.